# Euro symbol encoding - PHP

Tags: php, curl, encoding, euro

I've tried a lot of different things and can't get the euro symbol to show.
I'm using cURL to parse a page. The page is encoded in ISO-8859-1

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

There's a euro symbol on the page and when I use

```
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
```

I just get a black diamond with a question mark inside.

I've seen a lot of questions and answers on this site that were related but they didn't really work.

**EDIT :** I've tried to use the following:

```
$curl_scraped_page = preg_replace('/charset=(.*)"/', 'charset="UTF-8"', $curl_scraped_page);
```

and

```
$curl_scraped_page = iconv('iso-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $curl_scraped_page);
```

and

```
$curl_scraped_page = utf8_encode(curl_exec($ch));
```

I guess another question is, to display the euro sign, do I need to use UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1?

**EDIT2 :** I've tried this:

```
echo "Encoding is $enc";
echo iconv($enc, "ISO-8859-1", $curl_scraped_page);
```

The result was:

```
Encoding is ISO-8859-1
```

but there were still no euro symbols.
When I view the source of the page, it still shows the diamond question marks but when I click 'View' on the browser and change it to ISO-8859-1, the euro symbols appear. So is it a browser issue?

Comment: Unless you tell us what you've already tried and what was not working, it's going to be difficult to help :) As a general comment, have you tried using PHP's `utf8_encode` function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: Ok, so it's working now! I can't actually find the person who gave me the advice because I think they deleted the post, but thank you, if you see this! I set cURL to parse in ISO-8859-1 encoding, before I do the cURL parse: **header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set cURL to parse in ISO-8859-1 encoding, before I do the cURL parse

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
```

This means that it takes the Euro symbol in as it is on the page.
Then when I echo the content with the Euro symbol, I don't have to worry about the encoding because I think it automatically formats to whichever encoding I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the header for curl

```
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

its possible that curl make as default a "UTF-8" connection.

Edit:

What is when you convert it to iso with "utf8_decode" ?

[PHP: curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't work.
I presume your variable $curl is supposed to be my $ch.

Comment: The you should give is moren information about. your return in UTF-8 this is why you see the questionmark sign. So you have to convert your return back to ISO.

Answer (score 1):

Just Apply `htmlentities(curl_exec($ch))`
This will not break at special characters

Answer (score 0):

Just add the same meta Content-Type declaration to the webpage you're echo-ing the retrieved page on.

Comment: I tried: $text = iconv($$curl_scraped_page, "ISO-8859-1", $text); echo $text; -- but it didn't work.

Comment: No, I meant adding this line: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`

Answer (score 0):

web browsers dont use the meta tag to determine the charset unless there is no http header present which declares the charset. It's the fallback, and most webservers specify the charset via http header, so meta tags are generally ignored in practice.

I'm saying: that page could be a different charset.

Check the http headers. Then declare you own page to match, again, via http headers, not the meta tag. Or convert the string to your preferred encoding.